# Javascript function event.target.getAttribute("src") returns null

Tags: javascript

I have this list of images

```
    <div class="item board col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mb-4" onclick="show()">
    <a href="#" class="item-wrap fancybox">
      <div class="work-info">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
        <span>TEXT</span>
      </div>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/image-9.jpg" >
    </a>
  </div>


    <div class="item maison col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mb-4" onclick="show()">
    <a href="#" class="item-wrap fancybox">
      <div class="work-info">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
        <span>TEXT</span>
      </div>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/image-1.jpg" >
    </a>
  </div>
```

I would like the the the full path of the image when I click on the div

```
  function show(){
    var img = event.target.getAttribute("src");
    console.log(img);
  }
```

However when I look in the console it returns null why is that?

Comment: What **should** it return? The `div` you bound the event to has no `src` attribute

Comment: You must understand first what is the `event.target` property!  

When an event is fired, the element that fires the event is known as the emitter. This element is what we call the target. So, the target property of that event object refers to the event emitter. So, in your case, the emitter is the "div" and that element doesn't have an attribute called "src".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the `onclick` is on the `div` and not on the `img` if you update `show` to the following:

```js
  function show(){
    var img = event.target.querySelector("img").getAttribute("src");
    console.log(img);
  }
```

it should work

Comment: Thank you it is exacly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

If you click exactly on the image, the src value is properly displayed in the console, but if you click in other element you will get a null. Try it.
That happens because all elements inside the div are heritaging the event handler onclick="show()", but when the event is triggered what is passed as argument is the exact element on which you have clicked, thats why if you don't click the image exactly but another element, the src attribute is not there and of course a null value is display.
SOLUTION: Move the event handler to the img tag in this way, take it off from the div tag.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="img/image-9.jpg" onclick="show()" >
```

```js
function show(){
    var img = event.target.getAttribute("src");
    console.log(img);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="item board col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mb-4" >
    <a href="#" class="item-wrap fancybox">
      <div class="work-info">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
        <span>TEXT</span>
      </div>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/image-9.jpg" onclick="show()" >
    </a>
  </div>


    <div class="item maison col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mb-4" >
    <a href="#" class="item-wrap fancybox">
      <div class="work-info">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
        <span>TEXT</span>
      </div>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/image-1.jpg" onclick="show()">
    </a>
  </div>
```